# Nginx custom 404 page with php not working

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use a custom 404.php page for 404 errors instead of the default nginx error page, but everything I tried so far won't work. I can serve a custom 404.html page with no problems, but can't get it to work for php. The following is what I tried in my default config with no luck.

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

I also tried

```
error_page 404 = /404.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

I'm using nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you have static page 404.php?

Comment: @IgorCova I have a 404.php page in my root directory.  /var/www/html/404.php

Comment: add rows `root  /var/www/html;` and `internal;` after `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;`

Comment: @IgorCova I just tried that unfortunately it's still displaying the default nginx 404.

Comment: Did you do reload nginx?

Comment: @IgorCova I tried reloading and restarting with no luck.

Comment: Is your nginx.conf file include conf of your site, that you described?

Comment: @IgorCova yea my nginx.conf has all the code included in it. If I switch the 404.php   to 404.html my html page displays fine, but for some reason it won't display my php page.

Comment: @IgorCova Thanks I just fixed it. The problem was I rewrote  page.php extensions to page with out an extension once I removed the .php extension like so the code worked. error_page 404 = /404; instead of error_page 404 = /404.php;

Comment: @IgorCova  Thanks for the help! put that down as your answer and I'll except it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite row in your conf file `error_page 404 /404.php;` to `error_page 404 /404;`

Check if your nginx.conf file included file conf of your site, that you described

Don't forget to reload `nginx` via command `systemctl reload nginx` after changes, and also you can check syntax via command `nginx -t` before `reload`